# Youtube JavaScript API - Pause audio when either youtube video plays

Tags: javascript, user-controls, youtube, html5-audio

I have background noise on a website which the client wants playing on loop throughout the website, so I have set up an `<audio>` tag which autoplays and loops.

On several pages, I have multiple Youtube embedded iframes which are declared using the embedded code from the youtube video pages, for example:

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y3OR9HnB14I?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

What they want, is that when a youtube video is played / resumed, the audio pauses and when a youtube video is stopped / paused then resume the audio.

Has anyone got an idea on how to do this using the Youtube Javascript API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the Youtube Javascript Player API to do this. You can listen to the onStateChange event on all your embedded players, when a "1" (playing) comes from any of them, you pause the . When either "2" (paused) or "0" (ended) comes you can resume the  again.

This works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      var player = null;
      var lobbyAudio = null;

      function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerapiid) {
        player = document.getElementById(playerapiid);
        lobbyAudio = document.getElementById('lobby-audio');
        player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onYouTubePlayerStateChange");
      }

      function onYouTubePlayerStateChange(state) {
        switch (state) {
          case 1:  // playing
            lobbyAudio.pause();
            break;
          case 0:  // ended
          case 2:  // paused
            lobbyAudio.play();
            break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  <body>
    <audio id="lobby-audio" src="lobby-audio.mp3" autoplay="True" controls="True" loop="True"></audio>

    <object width="640" height="360">
      <param name="movie"
      value="https://www.youtube.com/v/t-aOvEweUEw?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer1&version=3"></param>
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
      <embed
          id="ytplayer1"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/v/t-aOvEweUEw?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer1&version=3"
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true"
          allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360">
      </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to keep track of the state for several videos =) But a hint is that the onYouTubePlayerReady() is called once for every player on the page. You can specify a different playerapiid for each player to tell them apart. (in the example above i used "ytplayer1" for the single player.

- API Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
- API demo page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo
- The refrence to  could be useful too: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: With the two functions you declared there, do these override the Youtube Javascript API functions? I don't see anywhere in the code that you execute them - so I assume that these execute via the API?

Comment: I found the answer to my comment in the API reference. Usually takes me a few hours to get my head around new reference guides.. Thanks.

Comment: hehe. Yea, they are both executed from the API, like event based. onYouTubePlayerReady() is a hard-coded name. onYouTubePlayerStateChange I ask the player to call by calling addEventListener with the name first.

Answer (score 3):

from the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference):

> > Events
>
> onStateChange
>       This event fires whenever the player's state changes. The value that the API passes to your event listener function will specify an
>   integer that corresponds to the new player state. Possible values are:
>
> ```
>     -1 (unstarted)
>     0 (ended)
>     1 (playing)
>     2 (paused)
>     3 (buffering)
>     5 (video cued).
> ```
>
> When the player first loads a video, it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event.
>   When a video is cued and ready to play, the player will broadcast a video cued (5) event.
>   In your code, you can specify the integer values or you can use one of the following
>   namespaced variables:
>
> ```
>     YT.PlayerState.ENDED
>     YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
>     YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
>     YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING
>     YT.PlayerState.CUED
> ```

And for play/pause the video use:

> Playing a video
>
> player.playVideo():Void
>       Plays the currently cued/loaded video. The final player state after this function executes will be playing (1).
>
> Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.
>
> player.pauseVideo():Void
>       Pauses the currently playing video. The final player state after this function executes will be paused (2) unless the player is in the
>   ended (0) state when the function is called, in which case the player
>   state will not change.